# Storing UnUsed Dataabse and Tables for Sql 2008

Tags: sql-server

We are looking to upgrade the sql server from 2008 to 2017 which has multiple databases from few years back and don't have idea that really databases are much in use and those tables into databases are used lately or not, if not then we can obsolete the database or tables which ones are not used anymore.
We would like to get the results of Unused Database and Tables then store into table (Ex. UnUsedDBAndTables) and run through Sql agent job for daily or every 3 days and need to update the
How we can implement so we can check and analysis this table (UnUsedDBAndTables) for period of time and make determination which ones are really not needed to migrate.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find unused tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355662/how-to-find-unused-tables-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for the providing useful script. It's quite useful but when i run it's giving different results compare to other scripts so it's leads little confusions. What's the best way to monitor it? Is it if i run every day then how i can compare and analysis?